# Ceiling fan falls

Tags: electrical

My outdoor ceiling fan fell and pulled the wires out so far that we can't get to them to put wire nuts on them.  Could this cause a fire or can I wait to get an someone to come fix it in a day or two?

Comment: Can you post photos of the situation please?

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a picture? I'd like to give you a simple short it's ok answer but the only way to do that is to say turn of the power to the affected circuit.

1. A ceiling fan properly installed shouldn't fall but over time, who knows...
2. Most (but not all) ceiling fixtures (especially for a fan), have the power to the fan/light "only" - but the caution is that sometimes it has more, or is a pass through for a continuation of the same (or even a different) circuit.

If the breaker is off, it really should be safe.
If the switches to it are off, it *could* be safe.
If the breakers are on, and the switches are on, it is not safe.

You or the electrician should inspect the wires to make sure the sheathing did not get damaged/cut or the wires abnormally kinked.

Comment: Crucial piece here:  if the breaker is on it is not safe.  Jill, go turn off the switch on the circuit breaker that corresponds to this fan.

Comment: Thank you. I got the breaker off and hopefully all is well. I was very concerned that my house would burn in the night. I didn't send a picture because it is just a big hole and it is about 20 feet off the ground.  I think you helped me out!